# Validar formulario con un solo botón html

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, validación

Tengo un formulario que hice en HTML con algo de JavaScript. La parte superior del formulario siempre se debe de llenar, después el usuario de un `listbox` selecciona el formulario que desea responder y se muestra en la parte inferior, hay un formulario que se debe de contestar forzosamente. Cuando se le da clic en el botón enviar, se muestran los campos que aun no han sido respondidos, `placeholder` y `checkbox`/`radio`.

Lo que tengo que hacer es que un solo botón al final del formulario valide los datos que faltan y no tener 3 botones en cada sección. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Dejo la primer parte del formulario y la función que valida los datos y los `checkbox`.

```js
<script>

    window.onload = ()=>{

        var formulario = document.getElementByName('formulario')[1],
            elementos = formulario.elements,
            boton = document.getElementById('btn');

        function validarNombre(e){

            if (formulario.nombre.value == 0){

                alert("completa el campo");
                e.preventDefault();

            }

        }
        
        function validarRadio(e){

            if (
                !(
                    formulario.option[0].checked == true && 
                    formulario.option[1].checked == true && 
                    formulario.option[2].checked == true
                )
            ){
                alert("Selecciona una opcion");
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        }
        
        function validar(e){
            validarNombre(e);
            validarRadio(e);
        };
        
        formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar);

    }

    
</script>
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <div class="form-left-w3l">
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <br><br><br>
        <p>Nombre de la instalación</p>
        <input type="text" class="top-up" id="Nombre-Instalacion" name="Nombre" placeholder="" required />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-right-w3ls">
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <br><br><br>
        <p>Área</p>
        <input type="text" class="top-up" id="Area" required name="Nombre" placeholder="">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-right-w3ls">
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <br><br><br>
        <p>Fecha: <input type="date" required name="Nombre"></p>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="main">

    <div class="form-left-w3l">
        <p>Nombre del Operador</p>
        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Nombre-Operador" placeholder="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-right-w3ls">
        <p>Nombre del Supervisor o Responsable de Área</p>
        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Nombre-Supervisor" placeholder="">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="main">

    <div class="form-right-w32">
        <p>Marca y tipo del equipo</p>
        <input type="text" class="top-up" id="Marca-Equipo" required name="Nombre" placeholder="">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-right-w33s">
        <p>Lectura del contador-Horometro (si aplica)</p>
        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Lec1" placeholder="Inicio" >
        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Lec2" placeholder="Fin" >
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="form-left-w3l">
        <p>Número/código del equipo</p>
        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Codigo-Equipo" placeholder="" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-right-w33s">
        <p>Lectura de combustible (si aplica)</p>
        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Lec3" placeholder="Inicio" >
        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Lec4" placeholder="Fin" >     
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

</div>
<br>
<br>

<form>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Estimado, no haz probado utilizar la validación de bootstrap para tu comodidad??, en ese momento tu le das la propiedad de validación al boton submit hasta que tus campos sean llenados o seleccionados, te dejo un ejemplo. [BootstrapValidator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-usage)

Comment: Ummm no encuentro ningun radio button en tu html, si no estoy mal tan poco veo que exista alguna etiqueta en tu HTML que tenga el atributo name = "formulario" para que le añadas el eventListener, desde tu JS como lo estas haciendo. Por otro lado, la función document.getElementByName no existe, existe es document.getElementsByName. Por lo que considero que el código no esta lo suficientemente completo...

Comment: Me temo que lo que tu necesitas es un form steeps https://codepen.io/designify-me/pen/qrJWpG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pones los `input` dentro de las etiquetas `form` podrás sacar ventaja de las característica de validación del los formularios HTML, por ejemplo,

> Si el usuario intenta enviar los datos, el navegador bloqueará al formulario y mostrará un mensaje de error.

Referencia

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Validacion_formulario_datos

Answer (score 0):

Así no te va a validar nada, ya que solo tiene el botón dentro del form, en vez de tener todo adentro.

Sin necesidad de javascript y hacerlo con html5 lo que debe hacer es encapsular todo.
si lo vas a validar con html5, solo se puede poner un **button**, ya que si metes varios **button** comenzará a validar como loco.

```html
<form class="validate">

<div class="set-1">
<stromg>Nombre</stromg>
<input type="text" placeholder="Tu nombre" required>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="set-2">
<stromg>Apellido</stromg>
<input type="text" placeholder="Tu apellido" required>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="set-3">
<stromg>Ciudad</stromg>
<input type="text" placeholder="Tu ciudad" required>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<button>Validar y enviar</button>
</form>
```